# Wordpress theme based on author name

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display some content based on a post author in Wordpress. Here is the code I'm trying inside the loop

```
<?php 
$author = the_author_meta('first_name');
echo $author;
if ($author == "Rabin" ) {
echo 'hi rabin';
}
else {
echo 'not Rabin';
}
?>
```

But unfortunately this is not working. Every page/post is giving the same result. I've put it after this lines

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>    
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

I have placed `echo $author;` for testing and it is echoing the author's name but the rest `if else` function is not working.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is the "same result" does it echo 'not Rabin' every time? and what is echo $author giving you?

Comment: the_author_meta already prints. Use get_the_author_meta

Comment: It always printing 'not rabin' and the echo $author is giving the correct author name as it should. like if the author is Rabin then it shows Rabin if it is Jack then it shows Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "get_the_author_meta" not "the_author_meta".

the_author_meta one only displays it and cannot be used to be assigned to a variable:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta

Comment: Yes! it worked thanks a lot. By the way was that question so stupid? I got 2 negative votes instantly. anyway thanks again

Comment: No problem :) It's a newbie question ... the thing is you should try to do a bit of research before asking a question. Simply goggling the function's name would have brought you the answer you were looking for. And also experienced coders are so very not patient with newbies.